# How can I access the content of an HTML element from a node list?

Tags: javascript, html

I can't seem to access the content of certain elements and I think it must be because of the syntax I'm using. I'm trying to write and overwrite members of a getElementsByClassName list. I understand that it is a nodeList and not an array, but I still can't figure it out. Here's what I have/have tried:

HTML:

```
<span class="myclass">Text</span>
<span class="myclass">Text2</span>
```

JS:

```
var spanarray = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
//I've tried all of the following (for the record, I thought either 2 or 5 would work)
spanarray[0] = "Replacement text";
spanarray[0].innerHTML = "Replacement text";
spanarray.item(0) = "Replacement text";
spanarray.item(0).innerHTML = "Replacement text";
spanarray.item(0).nodeValue = "Replacement text";
```

I'd really appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: this might or might not be relevant, what browser are you testing on?

Comment: chrome -- I was testing it earlier at work with IE and I saw that IE6-9 doesn't support getElementByClassName, but at home on Chrome it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The following (your 2nd example) works:

```
var spanarray = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
spanarray[0].innerHTML = "ABC"
```

Here's a jsfiddle and try in your browser: http://jsfiddle.net/N4fjX/.

Post the remainder of your page if you've got further issues.

Comment: Well, this works on a regular element in the source, but I should have mentioned that the element I'm trying to change was generated by an external PHP file and it doesn't work for that. However, I don't see why that would be an issue because the CSS for the PHP-generated HTML does apply correctly.

Comment: Here's an example (from a separate file, and yes the script is after this is called):

    echo "<span class='myclass'>Text</span>";

In this case, a regular element from the HTML page is changed to "ABC" but this "Text" remains "Text". CSS styling is effective on this element, though.

Comment: The fact it's generated server-side shouldn't matter, it's what ends up on the client that does. There must be something more in how you're initiating the javascript etc. Is the javascript tag at the beginning or end of your page?

Comment: The script is at the end of the page.

Comment: It turns out that my problem was the PHP being called from an external JS function, so while the content showed up in the browser, the elements were not actually visible under "View Source" and therefore not accessible by the JS. I am going to post this as the answer in case anyone runs across the same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your comments, it might be the case where your Javascript is being processed before your entire page is rendered.

To make sure it has rendered, try

```
window.onload = setText(); 
function setText()
{
    var spanarray = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
    spanarray[0].innerHTML = "Replacement text";
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. It replaces an <h4 class="myclass">Text</h4> at the beginning of the page but not the stuff from the PHP file.

Comment: It turns out that my problem was the PHP being called from an external JS function, so while the content showed up in the browser, the elements were not actually visible under "View Source" and therefore not accessible by the JS. I am going to post this as the answer in case anyone runs across the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: in that case, you should try to put your replacement code right after the element is added in after ajax. Or under some other onclick triggers.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was the PHP being called from an external JS function via AJAX, so while the PHP-generated content showed up in the browser, the elements were not actually visible under "View Source" and therefore not accessible by the JS.  I should have mentioned the PHP part in the original post but I didn't think it mattered.

DOESN'T WORK:

loadText.php

```
<?php
echo "<span class='myclass'>This text should be replaced</span>"
?>
```

HTML

```
<div id='somediv'>
  <script type="text/javascript">loadText();</script>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spanarray = document.getElementByClassName("myclass"); //doesn't work in IE6-9
  spanarray[0].innerHTML = "Replacement Text";
</script>
```

JS

```
function loadText(){
  var somediv = document.getElementById("somediv");
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      somediv.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","loadText.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

SOLUTION:

Instead of jumping through extra loops with AJAX, execute the PHP directly on the HTML page. If AJAX is absolutely necessary, then I'm not really sure what the solution would be. Plymouth223 and Jonathan Chow have provided the correct JS syntax.